# Pygame sprite clamping isse

Tags: sprite, pygame, collision, rect

So Ive been having issues with getting a sprite to stay withing the bounds of the screen. I got it to work with a simple rect(0,0,16,16), but i cant seem to get it to work with a sprite being blit onto the screen. What do i need to change in order to keep my sprite clamped within the screen res? I only just started today using classes to orgonize code so any input is appreciated and helpful.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import Color


class Game():
    """ Lets try to get this going by simple steps
    One by one. First step, lets figure how to make a class
    that can do the display stuff. Lord have mercy on my soul"""

    def __init__(self, wi=256, hi=224, multii=3):
        """Initialization"""
        pygame.init()
        self.runGame    = True
        self.width      = wi*multii
        self.height     = hi*multii
        self.spritesize = 16*multii
        self.clock      = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps        = self.clock.get_fps()
        self.screen     = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        self.kl         = []
        self.walk       = [0, 0]
        self.speed      = multii*1.5
        self.x,self.y   = self.width/2, self.height/2
        self.playerSpr  = pygame.image.load('images/'+'link1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.playerRec  = Rect(self.playerSpr.get_rect())


    def mainLoop(self):
        """Loop through the main game routines
        1. Drawing  2. Input handling  3. Updating
        Then loop through it until user quits"""
        while self.runGame:
            self.clock.tick(60)
            self.events()
            self.draw()


    def events(self):
        """Time to handle some events"""
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if (e.type == pygame.QUIT) or (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
                self.runGame = False
                break                            
            if e.type==KEYDOWN:     
                if e.key==pygame.K_a: self.kl.append(1)
                if e.key==pygame.K_d: self.kl.append(2)
                if e.key==pygame.K_w: self.kl.append(3)
                if e.key==pygame.K_s: self.kl.append(4)             
            if e.type==pygame.KEYUP:
                if e.key==pygame.K_a: self.kl.remove(1)            
                if e.key==pygame.K_d: self.kl.remove(2)
                if e.key==pygame.K_w: self.kl.remove(3)             
                if e.key==pygame.K_s: self.kl.remove(4)

            if   self.kl[-1:]==[1]: self.walk=[-self.speed, 0]
            elif self.kl[-1:]==[2]: self.walk=[ self.speed, 0]
            elif self.kl[-1:]==[3]: self.walk=[0,-self.speed]
            elif self.kl[-1:]==[4]: self.walk=[0, self.speed]
            else:                   self.walk=[0, 0]

        self.x+=self.walk[0]
        self.y+=self.walk[1]


    def draw(self):
        """Draw and update the main screen"""
        self.fps = self.clock.get_fps()
        self.screen.fill(Color('purple'))
        #print self.screen.get_rect()
        #print player_rect
        self.playerSpr.clamp_ip(self.screen.get_rect())
        #pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), self.playerrect)
        self.screen.blit(self.playerSpr, (self.x,self.y), self.playerRec)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Grid2. FPS: '+str(self.fps))
        pygame.display.update()



game = Game()
game.mainLoop()
```

Comment: Use a normal blit. If the sprite is offscreen, it will blit partial or none automatically. What is `kl` doing? Perhaps you want keystate rather than key events for your movement type.

Comment: Hmm I dont really follow what you mean by 'normal blit'. I want the sprite to never be offscreen or hidden. I want it to stop at the bounds of the screen rect (even if I try and move it off teh screen with the movement keys) but still display. The `kl` and movement code is sort of a special way to both give priority to the most recent movement key while remembering previous keys as long as they are also still being held down. `pygame.key.get_pressed()` wont do that consistently afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `playerRec` to keep track of the position of your player instead of the additional `x` and `y` attributes?

I suggest also using the [`move`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.move) method (or `move_ip`):

```
def events(self):
    for e in pygame.event.get():
       ...

    self.playerRec.move_ip(*self.walk) # instead of self.x+=self.walk[0] / self.y+=self.walk[1]

def draw(self):
    ...

    # probably do this right after 'move_ip'
    self.playerRec.clamp_ip(self.screen.get_rect())

    # note that 'blit' accepts a 'Rect' as second parameter
    self.screen.blit(self.playerSpr, self.playerRec)
```

as a side note: You should consider using a [`Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), since it basically combines an `Image` and a `Rect`.

Comment: Thank you, i will look further into sprites in pygame. I will also try your tips there. Appreciate the example.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You are not stopping movement of the sprite when it comes off the screen.
   Make an move functions that will get a direction and will decide if it can move more to the side. That way when the right side of the sprite will be of screen, you will not move more to the right.
2. Since you put your direction keys in a list that works like a stack, you are only getting 1 direction per keypress. If you also want to move diagonally either make two lists one for both directions or use a easier method such as this:

   ```
   if KEYDOWN == K_LEFT: direction_x = -1
   if KEYUP == K_LEFT AND direction_x == -1: direction_x = 0
   ```

   do this for every key.

Comment: The method I have up take the best parts of both `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and `KEYUP` `KEYDOWN` as neither do priorities well by themselves. I actually dont want to move diagonally so that isnt an issue. My issue is how to get `clamp_ip` to work for my moving sprite. I can get it to work for the sprite rect, but then I just have the rect itself moving around instead of the sprite so when i move, the rect slides off the sprite and the sprite is gone, else I try and use the sprite itself to `clamp_ip` but it doesn't clamp and still flies off the screen.

Comment: Oh i see! So would me somehow forcing the sprite to stick to the rect, and then clamping the rect work? Ive tried your #1 but have not gotten it to work correctly. Still looking around for a standard way people do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could move the rect and then change the sprite coordinates to be the resulting rect coordinates after clamp